# Активировать radio по открытию модального окна

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Как при нажатии кнопки 1 открыть модальное окно с активированным радио 1, по нажатию второй - второй радио соответственно

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Кнопка 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Кнопка 2</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    Default radio
  </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    Second default radio
  </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Каким образом вы активирует кнопку?

Comment: Кнопка нажимается пользователем сайта, вручную так сказать

Comment: Похоже что при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. Как вы это объясните?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Назначаем кнопкам data-атрибут с индексом радио-инпута, который должен быть выбран
2. При загрузке страницы добавляем кнопкам обработчик клика, в котором:

   2a. Проверяем данные (наличие атрибута у владельца обработчика, и вхождение в диапазон)

   2b. Устанавливаем свойство `checked` у радио-инпута с индексом равным значению data-атрибута

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-target="#exampleModal"]'); 
  for (let btn of btns)
    btn.addEventListener('click', onShowModal); 
}); 
  
function onShowModal() {
  let item = this.dataset.item, 
      rbtns = document.querySelectorAll('#exampleModal .form-check-input') || []; 
  if (!item || rbtns.length < item)
    return; 
  rbtns[item - 1].checked = true; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-item="1">Кнопка 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-item="2">Кнопка 2</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    Default radio
  </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    Second default radio
  </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

В примере я сделал отсчет `data-item` с единицы, чтобы упростить проверку в обработчике события.